# Installing SSL certificate on JBoss

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, jboss

I have a server that runs JBoss. When I type bad URL to that server it gives me version like this: JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA - what version of JBoss that would be? A SSL certificate will be bought and provided for me so that I could install it in JBoss. I would really appreciate any HOWTO or any information how to install ready SSL certificate on JBoss. Do I need to generate any files with openssl, when this SSL certificate will be bought from some other company that sells SSL certificates?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The component you see displaying its version is not the [JBoss Application Server](https://www.jboss.org/jbossas), but the [JBossWeb](https://www.jboss.org/jbossweb), which is "[...] an enterprise ready web server designed for medium and large applications, based on Tomcat", i.e. one of the components of the application server stack.

The documentation for JBoss GA 7.x is [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBASDOC/Home), and for the equivalent JBoss EAP 6.x, [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/).

To setup SSL in a JBoss, start [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html/Security_Guide/Generate_a_SSL_Encryption_Key_and_Certificate.html). You need to know beforehand what is a [Certificate Signing Request (CSR for short)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request) and why you need one.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused here: I need to configure JBossWeb or JBoss AS to get SSL up and running?

Answer (score 0):

I would follow this guide from [JbossWeb docs](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/ssl-howto.html). Even thought its for version 3.0.x I imagine the ways to install SSL cert would be very similar if not the same.

I can see that you asked the same question on StackOverflow but I am not sure you were happy with the answer. If you are, you should accept it on the forum.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394478/installing-ssl-certificate-on-jboss